# How to use Codable to parse Json

Tags: ios, json, swift

Any time I try to use cod-able to parse json, I always run into an issue of my table view or collection view not showing the data. Take for example the code below; I am connecting to newsAPI to display the "title" field in my table view. I have my data model set along with the networking code in the request function. When run the code it shows No value; How do I fix this ? project link:https://github.com/lexypaul13/Nasa

```
struct ArticleData:Codable{
    var status: String
    var totalResults: String
    var article: [Article]
}
struct Article: Codable {
    var title:String?
    var unwrappeTitle:String{
        return "\(title ?? "No value")"
    } 
}



     func request(){
        
        let website = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2021-05-21&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=d32071cd286c4f6b9c689527fc195b03"
        if let url = URL.init(string: website){
             let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error)  in
                if  let data = data{
                do {
                    let parsedJsons = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ArticleData.self, from: data )
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.information = parsedJsons?.article ?? []
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }catch{
                    print(error)
                }
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where did you get the code from?  Whatever example is recommending the use of `try?` needs to be found and fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your `try?` to `try` so that your `catch` block is called when there is a decoding error and you'll get some helpful output.

Once you've done that and the decoding errors are printed, you should see that your `ArticleData` struct has a couple of problems, namely that `totalResults` should be an `Int` not a `String`, and `article` should be renamed to `articles`:

```
struct ArticleData: Codable{
    var status: String
    var totalResults: Int
    var articles: [Article]
}
```

Comment: I wish I knew which tutorial or example people are using that tells them to use `try ?` so we could hunt it down and kill it!  99% of `Codable` questions would be avoided if people used `try` and printed the helpful error that the decoder provides.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. To clarify, the variables in the struct Article Data should have type and name as the json itself, correct ?

Comment: @MayowaPaul That's correct.  If you want to use different names for the properties than those in the JSON your struct can include an enum conforming to the CodingKeys protocol, for more info see the section titled _Choose Properties to Encode and Decode Using Coding Keys_ [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types#2904057).